# ReferenceError: extend is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

I am trying to do a navigation menu onscroll shrinking in a Object Oriented Javascript way. But when in load page it comes to console log : ReferenceError: extend is not defined

here is the excerpt of my code.

```
function orvilnav( el, options ) {
    this.el = el;
    this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
    extend( this.options, options );    
    this._init();
}
```

And is the full code

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a20cd2859e7cb57c9e5b

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged jquery so I'm presuming your using jquery.

extend isn't a built in method to javascript but JQuery has a method called extend.

Change your code like this instead:

```
function orvilnav( el, options ) {
  this.el = el;
  this.options = $.extend( {}, this.options );
  $.extend( this.options, options );    
  this._init();
}
```

jquery.extend - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/